# How do I make an ASP.NET Core void/Task action method return 204 No Content

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How do I configure the response type of a `void`/`Task` action method to be `204 No Content` rather than `200 OK`?

For example, consider a simple controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("foo")]
    public async Task Foo() {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    [HttpPost("bar")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Bar() {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        return NoContent();
    }
}
```

I'd like both methods to return `204 No Content`, but the default (and thus what `/foo` returns) seems to be `200 OK`. I tried various things, such as adding a `[ProducesResponseType(204)]` attribute to `/foo`, but I haven't found anything that seems to have any effect.

Comment: What do you mean? Doesn't `Bar` return 204? As for `Foo`, if you want it to return a result it should have the `async Task<IActionResult>` signature

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: `Bar` returns 204. I'd like `Foo` to return 204 also, but without the overhead of having to explicitly say so; I think it would be a reasonable deafult for _any_ action without an explicit result type, so I would like to configure my project to do that application-wide.

Comment: As for `ProducesResponseType`, the [source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ProducesResponseTypeAttribute.cs) doesn't have any methods that actually modify the status code. The source hasn't changed for 2 years. It seems it's only used to add metadata for the API Explorer that say `if you call this you'll get back this code`

Comment: what overhead? Using a filter is actually a *bigger* overhead that just returning the status code. As for `reasonable default`, that's 200. POST means `Create`. A POST that returns `No Content` would be a surprise to any client

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The _code_ overhead :) I don't care enough about performance in this part of the application to care if it's done with an action filter or some other way, but I'd like to avoid having to write extra code to control the status code _in every place_ here. (My application has lots of `/foo`-like action methods, as well as methods returning regular 200 OK responses with method signatures like `Task<MyViewModel>`.)

Comment: The code overhead is identical. One line. In any case, you can create your own [Result filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#result-filters). In the source, you could search for classes that implement `IResultFilter` or `IAsyncResultFilter` for possible implementations

Comment: Searching the source I can't find any filter/attribute that matches what you want. As the docs say though, you can implement the interfaces directly or inherit from `ResultFilterAttribute`. [ProducesAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ProducesAttribute.cs) imiplements them directly to add content types. [This test class](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/ed9f8ce6c90316e1b891d8a75020f7fdd54a0133/test/WebSites/BasicWebSite/Filters/TraceOutputResultFilter.cs) shows how to create your own filter based on ResultFilterAttribute

Comment: you can also consider adding a middleware that can check if the status code is 200 and content is empty or some other combination of appropriate conditions to determine if there was no content, you can modify the status code to 204 in that case. You won't have to add any attribute anywhere in that case.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution that returns 204 instead of 200 for **all** controller methods that return `void` or `Task`. First, create a result filter:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes;

namespace StackOverflow.SampleCode
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A filter that transforms http status code 200 OK to 204 No Content for controller actions that return nothing,
    /// i.e. <see cref="System.Void"/> or <see cref="Task"/>.
    /// </summary>
    internal class VoidAndTaskTo204NoContentFilter : IResultFilter
    {
        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (context.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
            {
                var returnType = actionDescriptor.MethodInfo.ReturnType;
                if (returnType == typeof(void) || returnType == typeof(Task))
                {
                    context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = Status204NoContent;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Then register the filter globally:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options => options.Filters.Add<VoidAndTaskTo204NoContentFilter>());
}
```

This will affect all your controller methods.

Comment: Thanks for a ready-to-copy-paste solution up for the grabbing!

Comment: Just don't forget to rename the `StackOverflow.SampleCode` namespace. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

A workable solution provided by Nish26.
But if you don't want to clog up the controller by an excess code then another option is to create a `ResultFilter`:

```
public class ResponseCodeAttribute : Attribute, IResultFilter
{
    private readonly int _statusCode;
    public ResponseCode(int statusCode)
    {
        this._statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
    }
    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = _statusCode;
    }
}
```

And then use it with the action method:

```
[ResponseCode(204)]
[HttpPost("foo")]
public async Task Foo() {
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

BTW, `ProducesResponseType` is just an attribute that helps to create an API metadata.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think this is a good idea. Controller actions should be testable without creating the entire pipeline. You can test `Bar()` to ensure it returns `204` simply by checking the return result. You can't do that with an action that modifies the return result through filters.

That said, it is possible to modify the result by using [Result Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#result-filters), attributes that implement the `IResultFilter`, `IAsyncResultFilter` interfaces. There's also an abstract [ResultFilterAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Filters/ResultFilterAttribute.cs) class that implements both interfaces provides an implementation for IAsyncResultFilter that calls the `IResultFilter` methods.

You could create an attribute that modifies the status code like this :

```
public class ResponseCodeAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    //Public property to enable reflection, inspection
    public int StatusCode {get;}

    public ResponseCodeAttribute(int statusCode)=>StatusCode=statusCode;

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCode;
    }
}
```

And use it with :

```
[HttpPost,ResponseCode(204)]
public async Task Foo() {
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

*This is not enough though*.

Callers of this method have no way of knowing that it will return `204` instead of the expected `200`. That's where the metadata-only attribute [ProducesResponseTypeAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ProducesResponseTypeAttribute.cs) comes in. This attribute implements the `IApiResponseMetadataProvider` which is used to provide metadata to API Explorer *and* the proxy/documentation tools like Swagger. At the very least you should use both attributes, eg :

```
[HttpPost,ResponseCode(204),ProducesResponseType(204)]
public async Task Foo() {
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Even better, combine `ResponseCodeAttribute` with `IApiResponseMetadataProvider` :

```
public class ResponseCodeAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute,IApiResponseMetadataProvider
{
    public int StatusCode {get;}

    public Type Type { get; }=typeof(void);

    public ResponseCodeAttribute(int statusCode)=>StatusCode=statusCode;

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCode;
    }

    void IApiResponseMetadataProvider.SetContentTypes(MediaTypeCollection contentTypes)
    {            
    }
}
```

And apply it with the initial :

```
[HttpPost,ResponseCode(204)]
public async Task Foo() {
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: Unsure what you feel isn't a good idea; I *think* you are talking about the Filter approach someone answered with. If so, do you have any answers to the original question? While we of course want to write clean and testable code, we also want to observe HTTP expectations. For example, MDN is pretty opinionated that empty bodies should be accompanied by 204 status code. "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/DELETE

Answer (score 0):

Controller base class has a Response property of type [HttpResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse?view=aspnetcore-2.1).
You can directly set :

```
 Response.StatusCode = 204 ;
```

Comment: Setting status codes is the job of the `ActionResult` result value. Hard-coding a modification to `Response` breaks the MVC pattern and makes it *harder* to write and test controller methods.

Comment: I agree with you. Just to add to the conversation  NoContentResult inherits from StatusCodeResult which eventually inherits from ActionResult. If we return a NoContentResult from action method,  its Execute() will be eventually called which does the same thing as above by setting  context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCode; . If return type of action method is void, instance of EmptyResult : ActionResult is created which has empty Execute body. He could have changed the return type of Foo() to IActionResult, however, i assume he wants to know how does it work with void return type.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove HttpNoContent formatter from outputformatters.[Ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        // requires using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
        options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<StringOutputFormatter>();
        options.OutputFormatters.RemoveType<HttpNoContentOutputFormatter>();
    });
}
```